# How to express "have fun!" or "enjoy!" in Chinese?

Tags: word-requests, expressions

In English, when a friend is doing some activity, we typically say to him/her:

> Have fun!

or

> Enjoy!

How can we say this in a idiomatic way in Mandarin Chinese?

Comment: 玩得开心点 should do it. 谢谢你（的帮助） for the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

玩得开心 or 尽兴。 Seems that in Chinese, there's no equal saying of having fun.

Comment: Thanks to clarify, I did not know before that Chinese Mandarin do not use (have) this expression into a sentence. It think it's common used in western countries so that's why I was looking for it.-

Comment: This seems to only make sense to me with more "physical" activities. If someone told me they obtained a book they wanted to read and I wanted to say "have fun", I at least would not use the first phrase. Perhaps add a comment about this sort of discrepancy? You're right that there's no literal equivalent phrase though.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how to say "have fun” in this situation either. However, I would say "不错哦，看完记得和我分享一下". This will also strengthen connection between you and that guy.

Comment: It seems we should use "玩得开心“, not ”的“.

Answer (score 1):

尽管玩儿
It's similar to Beijing slang that we used to say: 你先玩儿着，我们下回再聊.